# escucha de eventos para calculadora

Tags: java, java-swing

Muy buenas.

He creado una calculadora bastante simple en Java que funciona (por el momento) pulsando los botones en la interfaz y tengo las siguientes cuestiones:

1. Por alguna razon, hay veces que al pulsar los botones estos no funcionan a la primera. ¿Que podría provocar este mal funcionamiento?
2. ¿Existe alguna forma de hacer que el programa recogiera los números por teclado?

Dejo el código aquí debajo, muchas gracias de antemano.

```
    public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private String textoPantalla, aux;
private float primerOperando, segundoOperando, resultado;
private boolean sumar, restar, multiplicar, dividir;

/**
 * Creates new form Main
 */
public Main() {
    initComponents();
    pantallaResultado.setEditable(false);
    setTextoPantalla("");
    setResizable(false);
}                      

private void button1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    asignarNumeroABoton(button1.getText());
}                                    

private void button2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    asignarNumeroABoton(button2.getText());
}                                    

private void button3MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    asignarNumeroABoton(button3.getText());
}                                    

private void button4MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    asignarNumeroABoton(button4.getText());
}                                    

private void button5MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    asignarNumeroABoton(button5.getText());
}                                    

private void button6MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    asignarNumeroABoton(button6.getText());
}                                    

private void button7MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    asignarNumeroABoton(button7.getText());
}                                    

private void button8MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    asignarNumeroABoton(button8.getText());
}                                    

private void button9MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    asignarNumeroABoton(button9.getText());
}                                    

private void button0MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    asignarNumeroABoton(button0.getText());
}                                    


private void buttonPlusMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
    notEmpty();
    sumarTrue();
    try {
        setPrimerOperando(Float.parseFloat(textoPantalla));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Cadena vacia"); 
    }

    setTextoPantalla("");
    setPantallaResultadoText("0");

}                                       

private void buttonEqualsMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
    try{
    setSegundoOperando(Float.parseFloat(textoPantalla));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Cadena Vacia"); 
    }
    seleccionarOperacion();
    setTextoPantalla(Float.toString(resultado));
    setPantallaResultadoText(textoPantalla);
    setPrimerOperando(resultado);
}                                         

private void buttonDivisionMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                            
    notEmpty();
    dividirTrue();
    setPrimerOperando(Float.parseFloat(textoPantalla));
    setTextoPantalla("");
    setPantallaResultadoText("0");
}                                           

private void buttonMinusMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
    notEmpty();
    restaTrue();
    setPrimerOperando(Float.parseFloat(textoPantalla));
    setTextoPantalla("");
    setPantallaResultadoText("0");
}                                        

private void buttonMultiplicationMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                                  
    notEmpty();
    multiplicarTrue();
    setPrimerOperando(Float.parseFloat(textoPantalla));
    setTextoPantalla("");
    setPantallaResultadoText("0");
}                                                 

private void buttonCMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    setPrimerOperando(0);
    setSegundoOperando(0);
    setAllFalse();
    setTextoPantalla("");
    setPantallaResultadoText("0");
}                                    

private void seleccionarOperacion() {
    if (sumar) {
        setResultado(sumar(primerOperando, segundoOperando));
    }

    if (restar) {
        setResultado(restar(primerOperando, segundoOperando));
    }

    if (multiplicar) {
        setResultado(multiplicar(primerOperando, segundoOperando));
    }

    if (dividir) {
        setResultado(dividir(primerOperando, segundoOperando));
    }

    setTextoPantalla(Float.toString(resultado));
    setPantallaResultadoText(textoPantalla);
}

private float sumar(float operando1, float operando2) {
    float res = operando1 + operando2;

    return res;
}

private float restar(float operando1, float operando2) {
    float res = operando1 - operando2;

    return res;
}

private float multiplicar(float operando1, float operando2) {
    float res = operando1 * operando2;

    return res;
}

private float dividir(float operando1, float operando2) {
    float res = operando1 / operando2;

    return res;
}

private void restaTrue() {
    restar = true;
    sumar = false;
    multiplicar = false;
    dividir = false;
}

private void sumarTrue() {
    restar = false;
    sumar = true;
    multiplicar = false;
    dividir = false;
}

private void multiplicarTrue() {
    restar = false;
    sumar = false;
    multiplicar = true;
    dividir = false;
}

private void dividirTrue() {
    restar = false;
    sumar = false;
    multiplicar = false;
    dividir = true;
}

private void setAllFalse() {
    restar = false;
    sumar = false;
    multiplicar = false;
    dividir = false;
}

private void asignarNumeroABoton(String numero) {
    switch (numero) {
        case "0":
            numeroEnPantalla(numero);
            break;
        case "1":
            numeroEnPantalla(numero);
            break;
        case "2":
            numeroEnPantalla(numero);
            break;
        case "3":
            numeroEnPantalla(numero);
            break;
        case "4":
            numeroEnPantalla(numero);
            break;
        case "5":
            numeroEnPantalla(numero);
            break;
        case "6":
            numeroEnPantalla(numero);
            break;
        case "7":
            numeroEnPantalla(numero);
            break;
        case "8":
            numeroEnPantalla(numero);
            break;
        case "9":
            numeroEnPantalla(numero);
            break;
    }
}

public void notEmpty() {
    if (textoPantalla.equals("")) {
        setPrimerOperando(0);
    }
}

public void numeroEnPantalla(String numero) {
    aux = numero;
    textoPantalla = textoPantalla + aux;
    setPantallaResultadoText(textoPantalla);
}
```

Código generado por Netbeans:

private void initComponents() {

```
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    button1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    button2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    button3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    button4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    button5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    button6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    button7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    button8 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    button9 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    button0 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    buttonC = new javax.swing.JButton();
    buttonPlus = new javax.swing.JButton();
    buttonMinus = new javax.swing.JButton();
    buttonMultiplication = new javax.swing.JButton();
    buttonDivision = new javax.swing.JButton();
    buttonEquals = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
    pantallaResultado = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    button1.setText("1");
    button1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            button1MouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    button2.setText("2");
    button2.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            button2MouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    button3.setText("3");
    button3.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            button3MouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    button4.setText("4");
    button4.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            button4MouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    button5.setText("5");
    button5.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            button5MouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    button6.setText("6");
    button6.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            button6MouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    button7.setText("7");
    button7.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            button7MouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    button8.setText("8");
    button8.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            button8MouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    button9.setText("9");
    button9.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            button9MouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    button0.setText("0");
    button0.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            button0MouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    buttonC.setText("C");
    buttonC.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            buttonCMouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    buttonPlus.setText("+");
    buttonPlus.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            buttonPlusMouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    buttonMinus.setText("-");
    buttonMinus.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            buttonMinusMouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    buttonMultiplication.setText("x");
    buttonMultiplication.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            buttonMultiplicationMouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    buttonDivision.setText("/");
    buttonDivision.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            buttonDivisionMouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    buttonEquals.setText("=");
    buttonEquals.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            buttonEqualsMouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(button7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(button8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(button9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(button4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(button5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(button6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(buttonC, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(button0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(buttonEquals, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(buttonMultiplication, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 41, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(90, 90, 90))
                        .addComponent(buttonMinus, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 41, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(buttonDivision, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 41, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(jSeparator1)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(button1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(button2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(button3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(buttonPlus, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 41, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGap(90, 90, 90))))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 10, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(button1)
                .addComponent(button2)
                .addComponent(button3)
                .addComponent(buttonPlus))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(button4)
                .addComponent(button5)
                .addComponent(button6)
                .addComponent(buttonMultiplication))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(button7)
                .addComponent(button8)
                .addComponent(button9)
                .addComponent(buttonMinus))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(button0)
                .addComponent(buttonC)
                .addComponent(buttonDivision)
                .addComponent(buttonEquals))
            .addGap(40, 40, 40))
    );

    pantallaResultado.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.RIGHT);
    pantallaResultado.setText("0");
    pantallaResultado.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.TEXT_CURSOR));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(pantallaResultado)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 222, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(34, 34, 34)
            .addComponent(pantallaResultado, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>
```

EDIT:

Siento la demora, he estado bastante ocupado, dejo el código que falta.

```
public void setTextoPantalla(String textoPantalla) {
    this.textoPantalla = textoPantalla;
}

public void setPrimerOperando(float primerOperando) {
    this.primerOperando = primerOperando;
}

public void setSegundoOperando(float segundoOperando) {
    this.segundoOperando = segundoOperando;
}

public void setResultado(float resultado) {
    this.resultado = resultado;
}

public void setSumar(boolean sumar) {
    this.sumar = sumar;
}

public void setRestar(boolean restar) {
    this.restar = restar;
}

public void setMultiplicar(boolean multiplicar) {
    this.multiplicar = multiplicar;
}

public void setDividir(boolean dividir) {
    this.dividir = dividir;
}

public void setPantallaResultadoText(String pantallaResultado) {
    this.pantallaResultado.setText(pantallaResultado);
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Main().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton button0;
private javax.swing.JButton button1;
private javax.swing.JButton button2;
private javax.swing.JButton button3;
private javax.swing.JButton button4;
private javax.swing.JButton button5;
private javax.swing.JButton button6;
private javax.swing.JButton button7;
private javax.swing.JButton button8;
private javax.swing.JButton button9;
private javax.swing.JButton buttonC;
private javax.swing.JButton buttonDivision;
private javax.swing.JButton buttonEquals;
private javax.swing.JButton buttonMinus;
private javax.swing.JButton buttonMultiplication;
private javax.swing.JButton buttonPlus;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator1;
private javax.swing.JTextField pantallaResultado;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: Hay varias llamadas a métodos que están en el código que subiste, pero no aparecen en ninguna parte, sería bueno si pudieras subirlos también para tratar de averigüar porqué tiene ese comportamiento.

Comment: @C.Rodriguez Siento la tardanza en postear el código restante, lo obvié completamente, espero que pueda ayudar en algo. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

Saludos, ProK.

> Por alguna razon, hay veces que al pulsar los botones estos no
>   funcionan a la primera. ¿Que podría provocar este mal funcionamiento?

Cambia el tipo de evento que agregaste a todos tus botones, observé que tus botones tienen un evento `MouseListener`, al tratarse de un botón, mejor agrégales un evento `ActionListener`, ya que no necesitan ese evento `MouseListener`.

Básicamente, sería de cambiar de esto:

```
button1.setText("1");
button1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        button1MouseClicked(evt);
    }
});
```

A algo como esto:

```
button1.setText("1");
button1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        button1ActionPerformed(evt);
    }
});

// Ese código lo escribí yo tratando de igualar el código generado por NetBeans
// Y cómo podría quedar después de agregarlas el evento ActionListener
```

Y así deberías aplicarlos a todos tus botones, con eso bastaría para que al presionar los botones funcionen a la primera siempre.

---

> ¿Existe alguna forma de hacer que el programa recogiera los números
>   por teclado?

Sí, de hecho existen dos formas:

- **Forma "relativamente" sencilla:**

Esta forma es bastante sencilla de aplicar, pero ¿por qué "relativamente"? Bueno, no siempre puede funcionar porque requiere eliminar el enfoque de los botones y cajas de textos en tu programa para que sólamente pueda enfocarse ya sea en el `JPanel` o el `JFrame` en sí (tu ventana).

Para esto requieres agregar un evento de tipo `KeyListener` (específicamente un `KeyPressed`) ya sea en tu panel (`jPanel1`) o en tu ventana (`JFrame`).

El evento generado debería ser algo así:

```
// Ejemplo con el evento KeyPressed agregado al JFrame
private void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
    switch (evt.getKeyCode()) {
        case java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_0:
            // Ejecutar acción al presionar la tecla 0
            break;
        case java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_1:
            // Ejecutar acción al presionar la tecla 1
            break;
        case java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_2:
            // Ejecutar acción al presionar la tecla 2
            break;
        // Y así realizas con todos los botones que quieras
    }
}
```

- **Forma un poco más complicada:**

A pesar de que suele ser la más complicada de adaptar (además de que te genera más código), esta es la definitiva para solucionar los problemas de enfoques que podría presentar tu programa, puesto que sólo implicaría tener tu aplicación visible y enfocada (no se requiere eliminar enfoques a los demás componentes).

Esta forma se realiza directamente en el `JPanel`, por medio de los `Key Bindings`(te invito a investigar un poco más sobre ese tema):

```
InputMap map = jPanel1.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW); // Te permite ejecutar las acciones con solo que la ventana esté visible y enfocada
ActionMap action = jPanel1.getActionMap();

map.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_0, 0), "KEY_0");
action.put("KEY_0", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        button0ActionPerformed(e);
    }
});
map.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_1, 0), "KEY_1");
action.put("KEY_1",  new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        button1ActionPerformed(e);
    }
});
// Y así con todas las teclas.
```

---

**NOTA:**

Los ejemplos anteriores fueron basados en un programa generado por NetBeans para adaptarse a tu pregunta. Sin embargo, si piensas hacerlo por tu cuenta (lo cuál sería mucho más ordenado) podría verse más beneficiado al no tener que utilizar más código de la cuenta, adicionando el conocimiento que adquieres.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tomarte la molestia de responder a esta pregunta, llevaba varios dias dándole vueltas a esta cuestión sin conseguir un resultado (como programador junior inexperto, aun no he desarrollado una buena lógica). Probaré en un futuro no muy lejano a realizarla desde 0 siguiendo tus consejos. Nuevamente, mil gracias.

Comment: ¡Perfecto! No olvides que si te ha servido como respuesta a tu pregunta márcala como respondida.